# Unity with ML Agents - OnActionReceived is always empty

Tags: unity-game-engine

My code is really simple :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.MLAgents;
using Unity.MLAgents.Actuators;

public class move : Agent
{

    public override void OnActionReceived(ActionBuffers actions)
    {
        Debug.Log(actions.DiscreteActions[0]);
    }
}
```

I have "Discrete Actions" enabled in the Behavior Parameters and I'm using 1000 Max Steps. I'm using a simple Cube as a GameObject with those 2 scripts attached - the Behavior Parameters and the test script. I am running "mlagents--learn" and I get no errors or warnings it cannot connect (I do if I don't run mlagents first, so I'm asuming it has a connection). Is there any reason why I never get any actions? It's been giving me a headache for a few days, help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you attached a DecisionRequester() to the gameobject as well?
If you havnt attached it, then you have to call it yourself. Else the agent will never move.